# Pass Symfony form errors to session and apply to another form (of the same type)

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I need to pass the a FormType using session, but the object is too huge and breaks the server, even serialized.

Is there anyway I can pass just the form errors using the session, just so I can apply the errors to another form (of the same type) later?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this but you'll be losing `FormError` context and be left with only error messages (string type). Is that suitable enough for you?

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form-isValid()){
    // form is valid, proceed with logic
}else{
    /** @var FormError[] **/
    $errors = $form->getErrors();
    $text_errors = array();

    if ( count($errors)){   
        foreach ( $error as $e ){
            $text_error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $session = new Session(); // maybe unnecesarry, if you've already created it
        $session->set("my.form.errors", $text_error);
    }

    // Proceed with error handling...   
}
```